# [[Set]] attribute of the object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

While reading `Principles of Object-Oriented JavaScript` I came across the following line on end of [page 32](https://www.nostarch.com/download/samples/oojs_ch03.pdf) of free chapter on author's website :

> When a property is first added to an object, JavaScript uses an
>   internal method called [[Put]] on the object. The [[Put]] method
>   creates a spot in the object to store the property.
>
> When a new value is assigned to an existing property, a separate
>   operation called [[Set]] takes place. This operation replaces the
>   current value of the property with the new one.

The author talks here of changing value of *named data property* which happens due to internal attribute of object called [[Set]].
I looked into [ECMA 5](http://es5.github.io/#x8.6.2) and found [[Get]] , [[Put]] but no such attribute [[Set]]. However [[Set]] attribute is available for named accessors in object.

My question is there any object internal attribute called [[Set]] ? If not then how does changing of value of data property happens ?

Comment: ES5 is ancient, the latest one is ES2016 and this year we will get ES2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because [[Put]] was renamed to [[Set]] in ECMAScript 6.

- [ES6 9.1.9 - [[Set]] ( P, V, Receiver)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-set-p-v-receiver) for ordinary objects
- [ES6 Table 5 - Essential Internal Methods](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#table-5)

Specifically, from [Early ES6 Working Drafts](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:older_es6_drafts),

- Rev 12 (November 22, 2012 Draft)

  > Replaced [[Get]]/[[Put]] with [[GetP]]/[[SetP]].
- Rev 14 (March 8, 2013 Draft)

  > Rename [[GetP]] to [[Get]] and [[SetP]] to [[Set]]

In ES5 there was a [[Put]] internal method and no [[Set]]. In ES6 there was a [[Set]] internal method and no [[Put]]. More or less, they behave the same.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please have a look. He talks of [[put]] too.

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin I think the author of the text got confused by the differences between ES5 and ES6

Comment: So, according to ES6 for both purposes  (setting and changing)   [[set]] is used ?

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin Yes